(Godot 4.3) How to force richtextlabel to use mono font only
I would like to make the RichTextLabel node only use mono-spaced font, but just placing a mono font (not placing a normal font) doesn't work. Also, placing mono font in the normal font seems to offset characters when using color tags, for example.
the only thing I know is that you can use push_mono(), but is there other way?

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue you described. I set a monospaced font for the RichTextLabel for both normal and mono font in the theme section, and I was still able to use color tags without any problems, as shown in the screenshot. I suggest trying the same settings on your end to see if it resolves the issue. If the problem persists, please provide more details about your setup or any additional context that might help diagnose the issue.


in order to reproduce my problem do this:

create 2 richtextlabel with same text and font settings
make them the same position (one above another)
now in the front label use a color tag for each letter:
[color=#FF0000]h[/color][color=#FF7F00]e[/color][color=#FFFF00]l[/color][color=#00FF00]l[/color][color=#0000FF]o[/color] [color=#4B0082]w[/color][color=#8A2BE2]o[/color][color=#FF00FF]r[/color][color=#00FFFF]l[/color][color=#FFC0CB]d[/color]

the expected bug is that the front text will be offset related to the background text

I couldn't achieve the desired result using the exact approach you mentioned. I only succeeded when I didn't change the font for the normal RichTextLabel. This makes sense since each font has its own offsets and other characteristics.

this is really weird because I'm using monospaced font.

Can you please provide the name of the font you are using?

its called anonymous pro

It's the font I think. Try with other fonts, for example Space Mono.

Also I wanted to add that if you want the label to use monofont by filling just the mono font section (Not the normal section), you should use proper tags, For example [code]. Like in "hello [code] world [/code]", the "world" will be shown in mono.
